# php uasort in OOP

Tags: php, sorting

```
class DBNews {

    public function get_latest_posts($limit){

        // code goes here

        $posts_array = array();
        uasort($posts_array, $this->cmp);

    }

    public function cmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

I get the following warning :

```
Warning: uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, 
no array or string given in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\news\admin\functions.php on line 554.
```

And the 554th line contains `uasort($posts_array, $this->cmp)`.

Where to make use of the string or array and in what way?

**EDIT** : If I use `uasort($posts_array, array($this, 'cmp'));`, I get the following warning:

```
uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback,
array must have exactly two members in
C:\xampp\htdocs\news\admin\functions.php on line 554
```

Comment: uasort($posts_array, array($this,'cmp'));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have >= 5.3 and you're not using the compare method in any other function, you can also use closures:

```
uasort($posts_array, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Just nice then :)

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Not sure, it works [in this code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/t7jNIs) just fine.

Answer (score 8):

You have to call it like this:

```
uasort($posts_array, Array ( $this, 'cmp');
```

The following link explains how you can construct a valid callback in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: How are you calling `get_latest_posts`?

Comment: @JanHančič,  `$DbNews = new DbNews(); $latest_posts=$DbNews->get_latest_posts(5);`

Answer (score 5):

```
uasort($posts_array, array($this, 'cmp'));
```

Comment: You're not calling DBNews::get_latest_posts() statically are you?