# Sorting HTML tables without MySQL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, youtube-api

I have a table that looks like this:

```
            _____________________________________________
            NAME | VIEWS | COMMENTS| SUBSCRIBERS | VIDEOS
            ---------------------------------------------
            X    | 10    | 5       | 20          | 5
            ---------------------------------------------
            Y    | 50    | 10      | 10          | 5     
            ---------------------------------------------
```

My question is that how will I get Channel Y at the top of the table because I'm sorting this table as the channel with most views, I am not using MySQL. Here is my code:

```
    @foreach($data["statistics"]["members"] as $key =>$member)
  @foreach($member["channels"] as $channel)  
    <tr>
    <td>{= $channel["snippet"]["title"] =}</td>
    <td>{= $channel["statistics"]["viewCount"] =}</td>
    <td>{= $channel["statistics"]["commentCount"] =}</td>
    <td>{= $channel["statistics"]["subscriberCount"] =}</td>
    <td>{= $channel["statistics"]["videoCount"] =}</td>
    </tr>
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your source array is `$data["statistics"]["members"]`, so sort that, or copy it into a new array and then sort that. You can use `usort()`. You can remove all the `@` too, it's most unusual to put them on `foreach` constructs.

Comment: thank you, could you give me an example on how to use usort()? i think it needs two arrays but i'm using a foreach loop which could have more than two arrays.

Comment: `@foreach` is a blade marker, and is standard for all blade templates. It's not the same php suppressant that you're thinking

Comment: Ah, good point - your source array is `$member["channels"]`, in fact. There's an example on the PHP website, but fwiw I would do this: `<?php foreach(channelSorter($member["channels"]) as $channel): ?>`. You can then define `channelSorter($inArray)` yourself - and return a sorted array.

Comment: @Chris, thanks. Most confusing!

Comment: @halfer Agreed! It threw me when I moved to laravel/blade too

Comment: In that case, I am not sure if `foreach` can call a function as I suggest above? @Growlithe may need Blade-specific help here, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try usort in the meantime and try to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP > 5.3 (Since you are running Laravel, you should already have it) , following should work.

```
 $channels = $member['channels'];

 uasort($channels, function($a, $b) {
     if( $a['statistics']['viewCount'] == $b['statistics']['viewCount'])
        return 0;


     return $a['statistics']['viewCount'] > $b['statistics']['viewCount']) ? -1 : 1;
 });

 foreach( $channels as $channel ) {
    // rest of your code goes here
 }
```

Hope this helps!

[php uasort in OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244455/php-uasort-in-oop)

Comment: hi and sorry for taking too long to reply, didn't work for me, it still displays the array in the order in which the foreache iterated it. i got my result as `string(5) "43269" string(4) "2038" string(6) "622183" string(6) "108517" string(3) "504" string(6) "610514" string(5) "54732" string(8) "19606567" string(1) "0"`

Comment: Above method works. I checked it by trying to sort an array with deep nested properties. I think why it does not work for you is that you try to sort middle level array of larger `$data` array.